# A-Frame using teleport-controls with shake.js events

Tags: aframe

I want to use [fernandojsg's teleport controls](https://github.com/fernandojsg/aframe-teleport-controls) on my A-Frame project, but the way I want to use them is with [shake.js](https://github.com/alexgibson/shake.js/blob/master/shake.js), one shake to make the teleport line appear and another one to actually teleport where you selected.

I've seen the documentations and came across the startEvents and endEvent properties, and I want to map them into the shake event... for me it sounds like I have to create a custom component to do this, but I wanted to seek help first, to see if this is possible without doing it.

So far I've made [this (glitch.com/ link)](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-taptowalk?path=views/index.html:70:9) but it doesn't work so far (please note that I've got some other libraries there that make use of shake, mousedown, and similar events... my plan is to activate or deactivate them depending on how the user wants to move)

```
    <a-entity id="player" wasd-controls tap-to-walk>
     <a-camera id="eyes" position="-.5 1.5 0" camera="" look-controls="" mouse-cursor="">
      <a-entity id="cursor" cursor="fuse: false;"
        position="0 0 -1"
        geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.015; radiusOuter: 0.019"
        material="color: white; shader: flat"
        raycaster="far: 5; interval: 1000; objects: .clickable">
      </a-entity>
      <a-entity id="texto" text="value:Hola;align:center" position="0 -.3 -0.5"></a-entity>
      <a-plane position="0 .7 -1" material="transparent: true;  opacity: 0.5; color: #ffec04; shader:flat;"  scale="1 0.2 1"></a-plane>
    </a-camera>
    <a-entity
    teleport-controls="cameraRig: #player; teleport-origins: #eyes; startEvents:['shake','mousedown']">        </a-entity>
    <a-entity id="step" sound="src: #step1"></a-entity>
  </a-entity>
```

Thanks...

Comment: Provide a minimal example in this question; not as a link.

Comment: Sorry I'll add it soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will need a some JS or a custom component to get `shake.js` and teleport controls to work together for two reasons:

1. `shake.js` emits its events outside the A-Frame scene on `window` where `teleport-controls` is not listening
2. `shake.js` only emits one event type, and you need to differentiate for `startEvents` and `endEvents`

But it doesn't need to be very complicated:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('shake-listener', {
  init: function () {
    var targetEl = this.el
    var count = 0
    // you could also initialize the shake instance here
    window.addEventListener('shake', function () {
      if (++count % 2) {
        targetEl.emit('shakestart')
      } else {
        targetEl.emit('shakeend')
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Then add `shake-listener` to the same entity as `teleport-controls="startEvents: shakestart; endEvents: shakeend"`

Comment: Everything worked flawlessly, thank you, I just need to know how to change the position to be the eyes, because it teleport me to where I already am, thanks again for helping!

Comment: Try putting the `teleport-controls` and `shake-listener` on the camera entity (or on a child entity of the camera) so that they pick up the viewing direction